# Initial clause of loop, need to reference a variable before it is declared

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Sorry for convoluted title, I tried my best to make it conscious. Well, if you have a better idea, change it!

Not to confuse you, this is *Emacs* Lisp `loop`, not Common Lisp:

```
(defun hxswfml-build-trie (alist)
  "Builds a trie (a list, containing number of hash-maps, each hash-map
uses single character for a key, except for `t' symbol, which, if present
as a key is the key for the value one has to substitute with."
  (loop for (key . value) in alist
        with trie = (make-hash-table)
        do (loop for c across key
                 with branch =
                 (or (gethash c trie)
                     (puthash c (make-hash-table) trie))
                 with first-time = t
                 do (if first-time (setq first-time nil)
                      (setq branch
                            (or (gethash c branch)
                                (puthash c (make-hash-table) branch))))
                 finally (puthash t value branch))
        finally (return trie)))
```

This transforms an alist into a tree made of hash tables, where each table contains keys, which are characters of the strings I'd later search for and replace. This is needed to optimize searching for multiple keys with, possibly similar prefix in the large body of text and then replacing them each with a corresponding key.

The problem is that in the inner loop I'd want to initialize `branch` to `trie` and then in all later iterations to set it to either new hash-table (created for the character not a part of a known prefix yet), or a hash-table which was already created for the character from the prefix.

Ideally, it would looks something like:

```
for branch = (or (and branch (gethash c branch)) (puthash c (make-hash-table) trie))
;;                    ^-----------------^------- cannot reference it here
```

And that's why I have the silly `first-time` flag, which I could've avoided. Can I somehow use `initially` form, or maybe restructure the function in some other way to avoid this flag and the extra `if` with it? It's not very important that this function be fast (the searching should be fast, but the building of the tree needs not), but it just looks ugly :)

Comment: It seems like this is an interesting problem, but I still don't understand what you want to do after reading it twice.  can you give some examples of how this works.  In particular what was your final solution?  huaiyuan's code as is doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
(defun hxswfml-build-trie (alist)
  "Builds a trie (a list, containing number of hash-maps, each hash-map
uses single character for a key, except for `t' symbol, which, if present
as a key is the key for the value one has to substitute with."
  (loop for (key . value) in alist
        with trie = (make-hash-table)
        for leaf = (reduce (lambda (branch c)
                             (or (gethash c branch)
                                 (puthash c (make-hash-table) branch)))
                           key :initial-value trie)
        do (puthash t value leaf)
        finally (return trie)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you explicitly mention refactoring as a potential option, I'd suggest to separate two operations that your function combines: the creation of a trie and insertion of an element into a trie.

If you would consider the definition of tries as a more modular data structure, you could for instance start with the following two functions:

```lisp
(defun trie-create ()
  (make-hash-table :test 'equal))

(defun trie-put (key value trie)
  (if (equal key "")
      (puthash t value trie)      
    (let* ((c (substring key 0 1))
           (child-trie (gethash c trie)))
      (unless child-trie
        (setq child-trie (trie-create))
        (puthash c child-trie trie))
      (trie-put (substring key 1) value child-trie))))
```

(As you can see, I'm suggesting recursion here instead of nested `loop`s - that might be a matter of taste, but it seems to me that that makes the code somewhat simpler and cleaner.)

Next, you might want to add functions such as `trie-get` or `trie-remove` etc.

With this code, converting an alist into a trie becomes a combination of creating a new trie and then inserting all elements into it using the above functions:

```lisp
(let ((trie (trie-create)))
  (mapc '(lambda (x) (trie-put (car x) (cdr x) trie)) alist))
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. Your points are well thought through. Of course, the change from strings to characters as keys would be quite trivial, as would be changing `equal` to `eql`. But you are right that the length of the keys is limited by Emacs' recursion depth. If Emacs supported tail-recursion optimization, this wouldn't be a problem. In the bigger picture, perhaps the most interesting point that remains of my answer could thus be the modularization of the `trie` data structure into more separated, re-usable functions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there's already a `trie.el` package that implements general tries in Elisp (disclaimer: I'm the package author). It's been around for some years now, and is available from GNU ELPA in recent enough Emacsen. Or it can be downloaded from [the package's web page](http://www.dr-qubit.org/emacs.php).

It uses AVL trees as the underlying data structure for the tries by default, instead of hash tables. But you can specify a different underlying data structure when you create a trie. All the standard trie searches (plus a few extras) are implemented, and are agnostic to the underlying data structure.

This doesn't directly answer your question, but might save you work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand it, but in Common Lisp I would do:

```
(loop for i = (foo) then (1+ i) ...)
```